# Why my jQuery show() function in php foreach loop work only for first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, foreach

I have the following problem on my wordpress project :

I have 2 div call "div_sc_1" and "div_sc_2" which are hidden on my page.
I want to show them with a jQuery function .show() if they are not "checked". "Checked" status is writen in my db.

With my actual code, If only div_sc_1 or div_sc_2 is not "checked", everything is allright BUT if both of the 2 divs are not checked, only one is displaying and I don't understand why.

This is my code :

```
foreach($list_id_scores as $scores){
    $id_s = $scores->id_score;
    $checked = $wpdb->get_var( "SQL query for 'checked' status");
    if($checked == "1"){
        echo " score n°".$id_s." is over<br />";
    }else{
        $div_id = "div_sc_".$id_s;
        echo $div_id;    /// this echo show me that my loop is working  
    ?>
    <script>
        var div_sc = <?php echo json_encode($div_id); ?>;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#"+div_sc).show(); });   
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

What is the problem for you ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Please edit the question so that the code is legible.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan. Edit done, is it better ? Sorry for my noobish performance

Comment: you are duplicating id. ID must be unique. Classes can target multiple elements. This is the standard behaviour if you duplicate ids.

Comment: @Rousto this is how to properly format and indent the code. not only for SO but for readibility of the code itself when you write, edit or debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a global variable `div_sc` multiple times. All `<script>` tags share the same scope, so only one value is retained. The .ready() handler only executes after all variables have been defined (and the rest of the page has finished loading), not in between.

It might be better to do this instead:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
<?php
foreach($list_id_scores as $scores){
    $id_s = $scores->id_score;
    $checked = $wpdb->get_var( "SQL query for 'checked' status");
    if($checked == "1"){
        echo " score n°".$id_s." is over<br />";
    }else{
        $div_id = "div_sc_".$id_s;
        echo $div_id;    /// this echo show me that my loop is working  
    ?>
    jQuery("#"+<?php echo json_encode($div_id); ?>).show();
    <?php
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: actually he is declaring several times the whole script tag. The script should be out of the foreach.

Comment: Sure, but apart from being ugly that's not really a problem. It should work just fine.

Comment: @jvdmr Thanks a lot ! It's working. now i will try to deeply understand why :)

Comment: @Lelio Faieta Tanks for response. My code is still not properly formated and indented ? I just want to improve my knowlegde of "how to do well"

Comment: @Lelio Faieta. How can i put my script out of my foreach ?

Comment: I modified my response to include @LelioFaieta's suggestion to place the <script> tags outside of the php loop, and also put all `.show()` lines in 1 function instead of separate functions for every `.show()`. Personally I think it's less readable like this, but it will give you better readable html/js as a result.

Comment: @jvdmr Thanks a lot, you're awesome, I understand !